# Is this racial discrimination and do I have a case?

Tags: discrimination

I worked for this company for 4 years. They gave me an inadequate computer. From the start it was smooth sailing until I started experiencing  errors and problems. During my employment I kept sending messages to IT about the issues, but received no response. So I asked my first supervisor and he told me just keep sending issues to IT.

Around the 3rd year of my employment. The company hired an employee who became my supervisor in a year. At this time jobs were ramping up and the guy who's position I got came back and was hired with a brand new computer and equipment. The company went on a hiring spree. The new employees received new computer and office equipment, while I was bogged down with the computer they did not replace or upgrade. It had gotten so bad that I had to take company work home just to keep up.

The Second supervisor put me on PIP because of their slow computer I had asked several times about. After the PIP was up I was fired for performance issues. I am the only Black American in this department. I have emails to IT and supervisors about this issue.

Comment: **Is this racial discrimination and do I have a case?** - Is it your contention that they racially discriminated against you by not giving you adequate resources to do your job? If so, you should contact an attorney. Personally, I see this as a very hard sell.

Comment: You really need to talk to a lawyer about this, in greater detail than we can get into it here. If the company has a 4-year or 5-year machine replacement cycle then you may just not have been eligible yet.

Comment: I don't think it's racial discrimination, however, it may be unlawful termination depending on your jurisdiction/contract.

Comment: Do not listen to the two answers given here. Find the web site for your State bar association, ask for a free referral to an employment lawyer who specializes in racial discrimination. Only they can tell you if you have a case or not. The initial consultation is usually free.

Comment: It may very well just be a tightly budgeted IT department that has enough funds for new hires but not enough to replace older hardware. It sucks, but allocation can be timing dependent. Granted, some reserves should exist to fix or replace truly faulty hardware.

Answer (score 7):

**Absent further information - I do not think this is Racial Discrimination**

I have heard that story countless times in countless organizations. New hires get fancy new equipment, existing staff have crappy equipment that barely functions *especially when it comes to IT*

And all those organizations, the makeup of the staff have been all as white as the driven snow.

Now - if you were dismissed due to your PIP and you have the written documentation that you were not given the tools to do your job properly (which is entirely possible) - then you might have grounds for unfair dismissal - but I can't really comment further than that as we are getting into Legal advise territory.

Answer (score 3):

> Is this racial discrimination and do I have a case?

No, you have nothing in your question that would convince me that it's racial discrimination, let alone stand up in a legal sense.

Comment: You have plenty of evidence that you were treated badly. But for racial discrimination it is not enough to show "I was treated badly, and I am black"; you'd have to show "I was treated badly _because_ I am black". That's difficult.

Answer (score 3):

You should ask a lawyer.

Argument for:  you were the only person treated this way and the only black person.

Argument against:  you were fired for a performance-related reason after a PIP (Performance Improvement Plan).

This is going to be heavily dependent on what evidence you have.  If in the US, there are lawyers who take cases on a contingency basis.  Tell your story to one.  Let that person figure out if you have a case worth continuing.  Do not pay money up front.  If it's a good case, the lawyer will make your former employer pay.  If not, no reason to throw good money down the drain.

At this point, there is nothing that the internet can do for you.  Either you have a good legal case or you don't.  Several people have guessed that you don't, and they may be correct.  If you can't convince a lawyer to take it on a contingency basis, assume they are correct and move on with your life.

The time when we could have helped you was when you went on the PIP.  At that time, you might have pointed out to Human Resources (HR) that you were the only person being treated this way and the only black person.  HR might have gotten you more equitable treatment at that point.  But at this point, the only person who could help you is a lawyer who you can show your accumulated evidence.